# Type unification question with lists of tuples of strings

Tags: haskell

Someone joined `#haskell`, and asked a fairly novice homework question. How do you sort two equal length lists of string tuples? In an attempt to help them - my Haskell sucks - I wrote this.

```
sortBy (\(x:y) (x':y') -> let { a = x `compare` x'; b = y `compare` y' } in if a == EQ then b else a ) $ let f (a,b) = a++b in f ( [("a", "b"), ("e", "b"), ("x", "b"), ("x", "g")], [("b", "c"),("b", "d"), ("g", "a"), ("g", "c")] )
```

I assume that's far from working. Why doesn't this work:

```
sortBy (\(x:y) (x':y') -> undefined) $ [("a","b"),("e","b"),("x","b"),("x","g"),("b","c"),("b","d"),("g","a"),("g","c")]
```

I get this error

```
<interactive>:1:67:
    Couldn't match expected type `[t]'
           against inferred type `([Char], [Char])'
    In the expression: ("a", "b")
    In the expression: [("a", "b"), ("e", "b"), ("x", "b"), ("x", "g")]
    In the first argument of `f', namely
        `([("a", "b"), ("e", "b"), ("x", "b"), ("x", "g")], 
          [("b", "c"), ("b", "d"), ("g", "a"), ("g", "c")])'
```

I'd put these on multiple lines, but I'm not sure where I have to break them to make them work (Haskell whitespace is goofy).

SortBy has a type of `sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]`
and my list has a type of `[([Char], [Char])]`

How come `a` can't be unified with `([Char], [Char])` to make

```
sortBy :: (([Char], [Char]) -> ([Char], [Char]) -> Ordering) -> [([Char], [Char])] -> [([Char], [Char])]`
```

Comment: I might be missing something but at a glance it looks like the comparison function you're defining is exactly the `compare` you get from the `Ord` instance for `([Char], [Char])`, right?

Comment: jesus christ. most awesome comment ever. very true. that it was defined for tuples is pretty cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the next

```
sortBy (\(x,y) (x',y') -> let { a = x `compare` x'; b = y `compare` y' } in if a == EQ then b else a ) $ let f (a,b) = a++b in f ( [("a", "b"), ("e", "b"), ("x", "b"), ("x", "g")], [("b", "c"),("b", "d"), ("g", "a"), ("g", "c")] )
```

It looks like a typo for me. `(:)` is a list constructor. Use (,) to construct a tuple